# Ionic Bluetooth printing POS command not working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, printing, bluetooth

I am working on this ionic app, and I am printing receipts using a Bluetooth thermal printer using this library.

https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer

I want to cut the paper after printing, because my printer has this feature.

```
BTPrinter.printPOSCommand(function(data){
    console.log("Success");
    console.log(data)
},function(err){
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err)
}, "1D")
```

I have tried 0x1d and "0x1d v 1" but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly have you tried to send that command? Try:

```
BTPrinter.printPOSCommand(function(data){
    console.log("Success");
    console.log(data)
},function(err){
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err)
}, "0x1d")
```

If this doesn't work you can try to edit the plugin itself to add the method but thats a bit more complicated.

In the Bluetoothprint.java file in pluginfolder/src/android try the following:

got to the following method:

```
 boolean printPOSCommand(CallbackContext callbackContext, byte[] buffer)     throws IOException {
        try {
        //mmOutputStream.write(("Inam").getBytes());
        //mmOutputStream.write((((char)0x0A) + "10 Rehan").getBytes());
        mmOutputStream.write(buffer);
        //mmOutputStream.write(0x0A);

        // tell the user data were sent
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Data Sent");
        callbackContext.success("Data Sent");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String errMsg = e.getMessage();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, errMsg);
        e.printStackTrace();
        callbackContext.error(errMsg);
    }
    return false;
}
```

change the method attribute byte[] buffer to string buffer
and change the line

```
 mmOutputStream.write(buffer);
```

to:

```
mmOutputStream.write(buffer.getBytes());
```

Also just to make sure your printer suppports that method you can try to directly put:

```
mmOutputStream.write(0x1d);
```

just to test if it works.

EDIT:

Try this byteArray i found:

```
public static byte[] FEED_PAPER_AND_CUT = {0x1D, 0x56, 66, 0x00};
BTPrinter.printPOSCommand(function(data){
    console.log("Success");
    console.log(data)
},function(err){
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err)
}, FEED_PAPER_AND_CUT)
```

Comment: I have tried it exactly like this and it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Try to edit the plugin file itself. I have updated my answer so you can try.

Comment: Great thanks.. I will be sure to give it a try, and where you said `msg.getBytes()` you mean `buffer` instead of `msg` right.. ?

Comment: Yes, eddited and fixed. :)

Comment: unfortunately the paper is still not being cut.. :(

Comment: hi, how can i print the image ? do u have any  native andriod plugin to work with bluetooth printer ? so that i will create with cordova custom plugin